# if checkbox check but input empty disable another checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one chekbox and one textfield

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="usr_zipcode" maxlength="10" name="usr_zipcode" required="required">
```

how to make jquery, when vehiche1 is check but usr_zipcode is empty or no value, it disable another checkbox , name checkme :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme">
```

i try to use below code but not working

```
$('#vehicle1').change(function () {

    var input1 = $('#usr_zipcode');

    input1.change( function() {
       var empty = ( input1.val() == '' );
       $("#checkme").prop('checked', false); 
       $("#checkme").attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a separate function to check or disable another checkbox like below

```
function checkOrDisableAnotherCheckBox() {
  if($('#vehicle1').is(':checked') && $('#usr_zipcode').val() == ''){
    $("#checkme").attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $("#checkme").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}

$('#vehicle1').change(function () {
  checkOrDisableAnotherCheckBox();
});


$('#usr_zipcode').keyup(function () {
  checkOrDisableAnotherCheckBox();


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try my code:

```
$('#vehicle1').change(function () {
   checkEmpty();    
});

function checkEmpty(){ 

  var empty = ( $('#vehicle1').prop('checked') && $('#usr_zipcode').val() == '' );
  if (empty) {
    $("#checkme").prop('checked', false); 
    $("#checkme").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }else {
    $("#checkme").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

This is a demo: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/zQavrN

Comment: `.change` on a input `type="text"` field is not a correct idea. Look for other appropriate function.